# Cast Abstract to Concrete type without knowing the implementation

Tags: java, generics, casting

Consider the code:

```
Number n=new Integer(20);
cast(n) //return's n casted to Integer

<T> T cast(Number num)//to cast from abstract to concrete implemenation
{
    // Get which implementation of Number this by calling num.getClass()
    //cast to Specific implementation and return
}
```

Is the above code possible ? Can casting be done when I'm not sure what the implementation is ? If so how should the above function be implemented ?

Comment: What do you expect to be at the left side of `cast(n)`? This doesn't make sense.

Comment: cast(n) should return an Integer so that i can access the functions in Integer.

Comment: than cast to Integer. You wrote "Can casting be done when I'm not sure what the implementation is?". But for a cast to make sense you have to know the target type.

Comment: Because Java is a statically typed language. What should the result of `cast()` be when `n` is a `Long`? Try a larger example and you'll see that this requirement just doesn't make sense.

Comment: Check my answer and see if that's not what you asked for....

Comment: @ALL:Please don't answer it's foolish question,my mistake.I'm deleting it once the answer's are removed.

Answer (score 0):

Due to erasure, `T` will be compiled to `Object` and the result will be an `(Object)` cast anyway.

(I've seen a similar question here on SO with a more elaborate explanation. Can't find it now though.)

This compiles however. I can't see how it would be useful though, but perhaps you can :)

```
class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Number n = new Integer(20);
        Integer i = cast(n); //return's n casted to Integer
    }

    static <T> T cast(Number num) {
        return (T) num;
    }
}
```

Comment: @aioobe: I did the same.but it will return an object that's it if i'm not assigning it to any type.

Comment: @aioobe: What i'm asking is, can the function 'cast' return an instance depending on it's actual implementation not by getting the type of which i'm assigning it to.Suppose i'm assigning it like this 'Float f=cast(n)' it will give class cast exception.I want it in such a way that i can call cast(n).<Functions of Integer>().

Comment: Then I think its `((Integer) n).<functions of Integer>()` that you're after. Or would you like to somehow be able to use functions of Integer also on floats?

Comment: @aioobe: No that is not what i'm after.It's a hypothetical question.I wan't to know weather we can write a function such that it will return the actual implementation of an abstract instance.Now in the above case just assume that i don't know that Number is holding an instance of Integer.But i can know it by calling num.getClass(). I'm asking weather using this information is there some way to cast it to an Integer (which is its actual implementation) and return it ?

Comment: *I wan't to know weather we can write a function such that it will return the actual implementation of an abstract instance.* Sure. But actually you don't even need casting. `Number cast(Number n) { return n; }` will return an instance of `Integer` precisely if an `Integer` is passed to it. How does knowing that `num.getClass().equals(Integer.class) == true` help you? Would you want to return `(Integer) num` in that case? Well what should the return value of the method be? `Number`? Then the cast to `(Integer)` doesn't make sense anyway.

Comment: @aioobe:Please remove the answer so that i can delete the question.This was a foolish question.I'm sorry.

Comment: Someone else may very well run into the same thought and find these discussions useful. I really think you should keep it.

Comment: @aioobe: But do you understand how stupid it was for me ask this.It's a bit embarrassing to keep it.But if you say so then very well i'll keep it.

Comment: I have seen at least one more question like this here on stack overflow. I actually don't think it was stupid at all. *I* actually learned something from it (initially I even thought it was impossible to cast like `(T)`, but it turned out to compile!)

Comment: @aioobe: There is a [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760415/how-is-the-generic-type-getting-inferred-here) i asked before on this.Maybe you'll find it interesting.

Comment: Yeah. Nice question. Surprising indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Casting is impacting on the type of the object not on the object.

so your method

```
cast(n)
```

will do nothing

Comment: Techincally, casting changes the type of the reference, the type of the object doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to do this:

```
<T extends Number> T cast(Number num) {
    return (T) num;
}
```

Or, better approach, it's a bit dirty but you get the point....

```
/**
 * @author The Elite Gentleman
 *
 */
public class Test {

    /**
     * 
     */
    public Test() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        Number n = new Integer(20);
        Double t = cast(n, Double.class);
        System.out.println(t);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T extends Number> T cast(Number num, Class<T> clazz) {

        if (num instanceof Integer) {
            return specificCast(num.intValue(), clazz);
        }

//      if (num instanceof Double) {
//          return specificCast(num.doubleValue(), clazz);
//      }

        return (T) num;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private <T extends Number> T specificCast(int value, Class<T> clazz) {
        if (clazz != null) {

            if (clazz == Float.class) {
                return (T)Float.valueOf((float)value);
            }

            if (clazz == Double.class) {
                return (T)Double.valueOf((double)value);
            }

            if (clazz == Long.class) {
                return (T)Long.valueOf((long)value);
            }

            if (clazz == Short.class) {
                return (T)Short.valueOf((short)value);
            }

            if (clazz == Integer.class) {
                return (T)Integer.valueOf(value);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }
}
```

Output...

> 20.0

Comment: Why would he need to look which implementation it is? Wouldn't it look like `if (num instanceof Integer) return (T) num; else if (num instanceof Double) return (T) num;` ... ?

Comment: @aioobe...I just copied pasted his code and added a `return (T)num;`

Comment: Your "better" approach doesn't even compile for me.

Comment: Even if it did compile it wouldn't do anything useful as the result of the cast is cast back to (Number) which is the non-generic return type.

Comment: @aioobe, you are right, my better approach didn't compile, I wrote it in a rush to a meeting. I've updated my post....

Comment: Instead of `cast(n, Xxx.class)`, you could do `n.xxxValue()`. `cast(n, Double.class)` could for instance be written as `n.doubleValue` directly. I don't see the benefit of your solution.

Comment: @aioobe, sorry...didn't know that `Number` class had those methods. Also, the `Class` parameter is to infer the parameterized type, otherwise I won't know what `T` am I casting into.

Comment: Thats the *only* methods it contains :-)

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman:No this is not what i want and i don't think not possible to do it after seeing so many answers.

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman:Sorry it was a mistake from my part.I just realized it now.I was trying to access the methods in of the concrete class through the abstract instance without having to actually typecast it.If you could remove your answer (as SO wouldn't allow me to delete questions with many answers) i'll be able to delete this stupid question and avoid further confusion.

Comment: @Emil, *was* perhaps confused, but we've all shed some light on this now, and now no one is confused :-) I see no point in deleting this question. Someone else may very well think of something similar and find these discussions useful.