# Generics in method signatures and casts?

Tags: java, generics

Why does this work?

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T> T getResult(Class annotated) {
    return (T) getResult(annotated, new HashMap<String, Object>(0));
}
```

How does the compiler know how to cast the return value? It can't know it at compile time: it could be anything. Does it do it at runtime every time?

Comment: [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3760415/306855)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy for the VM at runtime because `T` is simply `Object` due to [type-erasure](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).  In other words this:

```
return (T)getResult(annotated, new HashMap<String, Object>(0));
```

Compiles to the same thing as this:

```
return (Object)getResult(annotated, new HashMap<String, Object>(0));
```

Comment: So if it gets compiled down to return Object, then why can we do things like this:   Product p = getResult(....) without having to cast the return back to Product?

Comment: Because the compiler inserts the cast for you. And yes, that insivible cast can fail, as demonstrated by the second code sample in my answer.

Comment: @Matthew, @meriton: It's because there _is_ a cast already... inside `getResult`. The type `T` is inferred for the call from the fact that `getResult` returns a `T` and that result is being assigned to a `Product`. Therefore, `T` must be `Product` and the cast inside the method is effectively a cast to `Product`.

Comment: We need to distinguish between a cast at compile time and a cast  instruction in bytecode. Your comment refers to the former, mine to the latter. That is, there is no cast instruction with receiver type T in the bytecode of getResult(). There can - but need not - be a cast instruction in the caller of getResult().

Answer (score 4):

The type of `T` in the generic method is inferred from the context of a *call* to the method, if possible.

```
String string = foo.getResult(Something.class);
```

If the type of `T` can't be determined from the context (for example, if the result is passed directly as an argument to a method that is itself generic) you may have to specify the type yourself:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(foo.<String>getResult(Something.class));
```

Generic methods may also use the types they declare in parameters, which can force the parameters and the result type to agree:

```
public <T> T getResult(Class<T> type) { ... }

String string = foo.getResult(String.class); // ok
String string = foo.getResult(Something.class); // not ok
```

At runtime, generics don't exist so it just tries to assign the result to whatever you're trying to assign it to... if it's the wrong type, you get a `ClassCastException`.

Answer (score 2):

That cast is *unchecked*, which means that it is *not* checked - neither at compile time nor at runtime. To verify, compile and execute:

```
static <T> T magicCast(Class<T> clazz, Object o) {
    return (T) o;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    magicCast(Integer.class, "hello");
    System.out.println("The magic cast always works.");
}
```

Of course, that is dangerous. Consider:

```
public class Test<T> {
    public final T foo;

    public Test(Object foo) {
        this.foo = (T) foo;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test<String> test = new Test<String>(42);

        // after being passed through dozens of methods     
        test.foo.startsWith("hello"); // ClassCastException     
    }
}
```

That travesty of a variable holding an object that is not a subtype of the declared type is known as heap pollution. It is the reason why a compiler is mandated to emit an unchecked warning - unless somebody suppressed that warning.

It is therefore recommended to do a reflective cast where possible; for instance:

```
static <T> T magicCast(Class<T> clazz, Object o) {
    return clazz.cast(o); // reflective cast, checked at runtime
}
```

Of course, if you know the class at compile time, you should use an ordinary cast, because that enables to compiler to performn additional sanity checks, allowing it to reject casts like

```
int x = (Integer) "hello";
```

which can never succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you did not write how do you invoke this method. 
I believe that the code looks like:

obj.getResult();

In this case the answer is simple: the compiler adds casting to MyClass and if you decompile the byte code you see something like

(MyClass)obj.getResult();

The same happens if you invoke you method and assign it result to variable:
MyClass result = obj.getResult();

By the way I think that it is a pity that you added annotation @SuppressWarining("unchecked")
If T is of type "annotated" you should say:

public  T getResult(Class annotated) {
    return (T) getResult(annotated, new HashMap(0));
}

This is the usual way to work with generics. See classes Collections, Arrays, AbstractList.toArray() etc.

Comment: The original code is included in an api client class we're writing. We wanted to get around having to cast our return values - and having to pass in the class that we wanted to get back would be just as much extra code.

Answer (score 0):

```
int y=10;
int z=12;
```